# How may I skip inserting an auto generated id number in PostgreSQL using Java?

Tags: java, postgresql, servlets

I have the following code to input data into the database using java. However, first column is actually generated automatically by postgresql database. Now, how would I change the code so it does not touch the first column?

```
String sql = "insert into members values (?,?,?,?)";
            PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS); // I used RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS, but I don't know how to utilize it.
            pst.setInt(1, memid); // I want this line to be skipped
            pst.setInt(2, birthyear);
            pst.setString(3, familyname);
            pst.setString(4, givenname);
            // Executing the insert
            pst.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include the list of fields you want to insert in the SQL:

```
insert into members (birthyear, familyname, givenname) values (?,?,?)
```

This way the value for the first column will have its default (auto-generated) value.

Comment: null value in column "memid" violates not-null constraint

Comment: is the memid column set to `serial`?

Comment: make sure "memid" is autogenerated column

Comment: oh i see, nextval('cag.mem_memid_seq'::regclass) was not set in memid

Comment: thank you very much. could you be able to check my other question about searching from database please?

Answer (score 0):

suppose i have two column named "name", "email" ,
then i can use this code to insert values to the database containing table( std_tb) 
with two column

```
String s_name="ayman";
String s_email="mamstricks"; 
PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("insert into std_tb(name,mail) values(?,?)");   
ps.setString(1, s_name); 
ps.setString(2, s_email); 
ps.executeUpdate();
```

if i want to insert second column only, then i can use this code to same table containing two column

```
String s_email="ayman"; 
PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("insert into std_tb(mail) values(?)");  
ps.setString(1, s_email);
ps.executeUpdate();
```

but don't forget to set first column with null value , if you are using wamp or xampp then ,you can do this by going `"http://localhost/phpmyadmin/"` then access to your table then put tick mark on null box